# Installed Apache2.2 on Debian (squeeze), replacing lighttpd, now all .php files return an error 324

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian

.html files are fine, but .php is a no-go. My Wordpress and MediaWiki are not functioning, I made a page with phpinfo() that isn't working, and I am stumped. My error log shows nothing except for favicon requests. php5 is enabled, everything is there, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you run any php command on server, are you receiving any error message, run any php command like:

> php -v

if here you can't see any error that means php installed fine, then restart http daemon and check php in processess:

> ps -aufx |grep php

if still facing issue then only logs can help to find out issue. Check access log and error logs.

Comment: php -v works, gives me versioning and so on. I've done apache2ctl restart many, many times. The only process that matches is grep php. Access and error logs are and have been devoid of any info pertaining to it.

Comment: Edit the files



/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/suhosin.ini
and  /etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini


uncomment and change the line


"suhosin.session.encrypt = off"

Then restart apache for the change to take effect;


sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

The bug is discussed in gentoo here (http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276583)                      I hope it will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I get the same error.

Comment: Does apache2ctl -M list your php5 module? Is there a php5.conf and php5.load in /etc/apache2/mods_enabled ?